# The try-with-resources

Tags: java

I have a very simple question that seems to be stupid to me but yet asking .How BufferedReader call the close() method of Autocloseable interface. or how we can implement Autocloseable  that call the close() automatically.

Comment: It closes it when exits try statement.

Comment: You can not implement `Autocloseable` that it invokes `close()` automatically outside `try...with...resources`

Answer (score 1):

It's syntactic sugar.  The javac compiler inserts the `close()` call into the compiled class at the end of the `try` block where the `BufferedReader` is declared, as you can see if you disassemble the class file with `javap -c`.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing you have to do in your own code besides implement `AutoCloseable` and provide a `close()` method. Java takes care of calling for you the `close()` method at the end of the `try` statement. Consider the following minimal demonstration:

```
class MyCloseable implements AutoCloseable {
    public void close() { System.out.println("Close was called"); }
}

public class Ac {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      try (MyCloseable mc = new MyCloseable()) {
      }
    }
}

$ java Ac
Close was called
```

Answer (score 0):

`try(AutoClosable x = open()) {}`
is usually seen as short-hand version of

```
try {
    Resource x = open();
} finally {
    x.close();
}
```

There are two actual differences :
If both blocks throw, the autoclosable `try` statement will throw the exception from within the `try` statement, whereas the `try...finally` will throw the exception from the finally block. An exception from the other block would be suppressed.

In addition the exact behaviour is like this:

```
try(Autoclosable x = open) {
    //do something
} do_close {
     x.close();//not actually there - executed before catch and finally!
} catch (WhateverException e){
    //catch an exception
} finally {
    //finally do something
}
```

From the [Oracle Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html):

> "A try-with-resources statement can have catch and finally blocks just
>   like an ordinary try statement. In a try-with-resources statement, any
>   catch or finally block is run after the resources declared have been
>   closed."

So due to these two technical details it is not just syntactic sugar, but in practice it is used where formerly `try...finally` would have been used.

There is no actual way to imitate the behavior of try-with-resources for other interfaces than `Autoclosable` afaik. If you want to do some cleanup after a try you will have to either use `finally` or implement `Autoclosable`. Finalizers seem to do something similar, but actually they don't. I just mention them here to [advise you not to use them](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/java/MET12-J.+Do+not+use+finalizers).